# Ecto.QueryError on a subquery

Tags: elixir, ecto

For the following query:

```
sub_query = from sq in Database.Nestoria,
  distinct: sq.lister_url,
  select: [sq.place_name,
          sq.price,
          sq.price_type],
  where: fragment("cast(to_char(?, 'YYYYMMDD') AS INTEGER) >= (SELECT cast(to_char(max(inserted_at), 'YYYYMMDD') AS INTEGER) - 1 FROM nestoria)", sq.inserted_at),
  where: sq.bedroom_number == 1

query = from un in Database.Underground,
  left_join: ne in subquery(sub_query), on: un.station_name_slug == ne.place_name,
  select: [ un.lines_id,
            un.station_name,
            un.display_name,
            ne.place_name,
            fragment("count(?) as data_count", ne.place_name),
            fragment("Avg(CASE WHEN ? = 'weekly' THEN price * ( 31 / 7 ) ELSE price END) AS avg_monthly_price ", ne.price_type)],
  group_by: [un.lines_id,
            un.station_name,
            un.display_name,
            ne.place_name],
  order_by: [ne.place_name]

output = Repo.all(query)
```

I'm getting the below error:

`** (Ecto.QueryError) subquery must select a source (t), a field (t.field) or a map, got: [&0.place_name(), &0.price(), &0.price_type()]`

The strange thing is I've has this running in a very similar project without trouble. All the schemas are working correctly without any issues (Repo.all(Nestoria/Underground) returns fine).

Comment: Try `select: [:place_name, :price, :price_type]` instead of `select: [sq.place_name, ...]`.

Comment: That fixed it thanks very much. How is it that the original way didn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of the current release of Ecto subqueries cannot have a `select` with a list as the value. Even if that somehow worked, you wouldn't be able to do `ne.place_name` in the query in the question since `ne` would be a list, not a map.

You can either select a Map manually:

```
select: %{place_name: sq.place_name, price: sq.price, ...}
```

or use `map` or `struct`:

```
select: map(sq, [:place_name, :price, :price_type])
# or
select: struct(sq, [:place_name, :price, :price_type])
```

or just pass a list of fields, which is equivalent to the `struct` version above:

```
select: [:place_name, :price, :price_type]
```